Why does documentation take a large storage?
I have installed Mathematica v14.1 and after that i installed documentation file.
The documentation takes 9GB plus storage it is more than the program itself. As far as I know (correct me if I am wrong) the documentation is just like a reference manual for the functions, its not like a video game to take that much space on disk.
Also previously I had v12.3 installed. Its documentation was already included with the program and that was very similar to the v14.1 doc but that whole program wasn't even more than 3GB.
I am totally clueless what is this documentation anyway (other than searching for a function definition)? Why it takes too much space on my HDD?

It takes a lot of space because Mathematica documentation is not a simple textual reference manual as many other manuals, but is actually composed of many interactive Mathematica notebooks. They contain large expressions, images, videos, plots, graphs ... all of which take some space.
Here is a list of the largest documentation notebooks:

Also note that there are almost 6700 symbols, each of them having their own documentation notebook.
I suggest you open the documentation for StreamDensityPlot, and you will see it for yourself. For example, the following largest cell in the notebook is 17 MB*:


* As measured by "CellExpressionByteCount" in NotebookCellData.

Thank you, it makes sense now but how come the documentation of v12.3.1 mathematica i had earlier wasn't that much huge?
I could just click on the functions info and it would open the definition and examples from local docs, that was all i wanted, Now with this version (without doc installed)  It opens an online webpage every time I want to see the functions definition and examples.

@Asim, you are now asking two different questions. Note that before version 13, Mathematica was always installed together with the documentation, and only [starting in version 13], you can separately install just Mathematica without the documentation. I guess this is what happened for you; you installed only Mathematica without documentation, and that is why you're seeing the web version instead.

I am sorry I think I couldn't explain my question well. What I am saying is that with v12.3.1 the docs were installed alongside the program, that whole took 4.5GB in size, whereas with v14 docs only take 9.3GB, Does that mean they included 9GB of data only in the docs after v13? I only want the local reference manual for quick search of functions definitions that was possible in v12 without extra burden on HDD, while with v14 I had to install 9GB for the same purpose, is there any way I can remove all the extras and just keep the textual reference in docs in v14? Thanks.

@Asim, I don't think you are correct. Unfortunately, I don't have 12.3 installed anymore, but according to the official web page, 12.3 needed 19 GB of disk size in total! Also note that there is no significant difference in the "old" and "new" documentation, they are in the same format, and there is no "function-definition textual-only reference" that you claim to exist :)

Yes you are right. my bad.

maybe i couldn't find the right words to explain. By saying function definition textual.. what I meant was: when you mouse over the function name it gets highlighted and info symbol appears under it, then if you click on that "i" symbol, a new page opens with all the information about that function and textual reference about how it behaves and what are parameters etc.. THAT I call the textual-definition. And it is almost same as online reference manual except that it will open without internet. That I assumed should not be taking a large amount of storage. But now i get it.  u r right
